# how to write this in simple terms

Tags: sentence-construction

my friend calls me and tells that he had a fight with a guy and also said that tomorrow he is going to his home and also told he is going to US by next month.

this is how i write that incidents in my "diary":

> today my friend called me and said he had a fight with a guy and he also told that tomorrow he is going to home and he is going to US by next month.

is that right? if not how to write the above coversation in correct way in passive form.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> today my friend called me and said he had a fight with a guy and he also told that tomorrow he is going to home and he is going to US by next month.

So a few things:

1. Capitalization and punctuation are pretty important in written English.  Please try to practice these diligently.
2. Your example is what we call a "run-on" sentence.  This is a sentence that should include commas and/or periods, but instead just "runs on and on".
3. "Tell" and "say" are different.  Tell is a *transitive* verb that requires a direct object.  I have to tell *someone* (even if I just tell myself).  "Say" is *intransitive*, meaning I don't need a direct object.  I say *something* but not *to* anyone.

Otherwise I'm not sure what you are asking about the "passive voice" since none of your verbs is in the passive form.  If you'd like to know *how* to make the entire sentence passive ... well, that's a challenge since we don't usually make *every* verb in a sentence passive.

But I can give it a shot.  Let's start by fixing the three things I pointed out, and cleaning up some of your word choices:

> Today, my friend called me and said he had a fight with a guy.  He also told me that tomorrow he is going home, but he's coming back to the US by next month.

Passive voice (as best I can):

> Today *I was called by my friend*, who said he got into a fight with a guy.  *I was also told* that he is going home, but he's coming back to the US by next month.

Notice I just changed the two verbs where I am the direct object. The rest I left alone.

Comment: Not quite: *Say* is transitive; specifically, it is 'monotransitive', taking a single object, the direct object, the words you utter.  *Tell* is 'ditransitive*: besides the direct object, the utterance, it may also take an *indirect* object, the hearer, "He told us the truth". (But the hearer may be omitted, "He told the truth", or expressed with a preposition phrase rather than an object: "He told the truth to the police".) You are perhaps thinking of *speak*, which may be intransitive ("He spoke loudly") or monotransitive ("He spoke bitter words") but not in present-day English ditransitive.